# How to avoid Javascript Error in altair viewing?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab, altair

In python3 I have a dataframe on pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

nomes_dep.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 120 entries, 0 to 119
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Deputado       120 non-null object
Valor          120 non-null object
porcentagem    120 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 2.9+ KB

    Deputado                Valor           porcentagem
0   ITAMAR BORGES           1,225,322.51    1.60
1   CARLAO PIGNATARI        1,205,708.42    1.57
2   CAMPOS MACHADO          1,155,406.50    1.51
3   ALENCAR SANTANA BRAGA   1,149,436.08    1.50
4   FELICIANO FILHO         1,134,941.68    1.48
```

Column "Deputado" has names of people. And column "porcentagem" has the percentage that these people had of expenses in relation to the total of an institution

With altair I tried to make a horizontal bar chart, in the X axis the values of the column "porcentagem" and in the Y axis the names of column "Deputado":

```
alt.Chart(nomes_dep.reset_index().head(10), title="Deputados com maiores totais de despesas em %").mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X("porcentagem:Q", axis=alt.Axis(title="Porcentagem", format="%s")),
    y=alt.Y(
        "Deputado:N",
        sort=alt.SortField(field="Porcentagem", op="sum", order="descending"),
        axis=alt.Axis(title="Deputados")
    )
)
```

But in jupyter lab I had this message:

```
Javascript Error: t is undefined. This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the JavaScript console for the full traceback.
```

Please, does anyone know how I can avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"%s"` is not a valid data formatter, and so it leads to an error when the plot is rendered. Perhaps you meant `".0%"`?

For more information on format strings supported by Altair, see [d3-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#d3-format).